# How can I set the PWM for PIC16F1934/6/7?

Tags: microcontroller, motor, pic, pwm, embedded

I want to generate PWM of 5 kHz with a 50% duty cycle using PIC16F1934/6/7 at pins RE0 and RE2 (CCP3 and CCP5). I am using the MikroC compiler, and the code is as follows:

```
  OSCCON =  0X70;
  CCP3CON=0b00001111;
  CCP5CON=0b00001111;
  ANSELE=0;
  TRISE.RE0=0;
  TRISE.RE2=0;
  CCPR3L=50;   // for 50% duty cycle
  CCPR5L=50;   // for 50% duty cycle
```

I specifically want to use these pins and their respective timers. The problem is that with these settings I get a frequency of  1/(450µs) = 2.22 kHz, not 1/(200µs) = 5 kHz. What can I change?

Comment: "50" sounds like a wrong value for a PWM register for 50% duty cycle, unless you've configured your PWM to count to 100 only. I don't know your HAL/microcontroller, but I've never seen a microcontroller taking percentages instead of absolute thresholds for PWM units.

Comment: I will handle that later on, my main problem is the frequency.

Comment: the frequency is a result of how far you count, and from where. So, this is not separate.

Comment: again, I don't know this particular microcontroller, but typically a PWM unit has the logic of counting up, enabling the output when the pointer crosses one threshold, and resetting to 0 when it crosses another threshold (or counting down, or similar permutations of the logic). The PWM period is the result of a threshold. Sometimes the reset isn't fixed to 0, so you can adjust both "ends" of the counter cycle.

Comment: Which one of these registers sets the point at which the PWM counter is reset?

Comment: I guess it's the PR2 register, but I am already using it for other purposes in my main program. Is there any other way in which I can set it?

Comment: Use a different timer. You can user Timer2, Timer4 or Timer6 as your PWM timebase.

Comment: The built-in PWM function requires use of timer 2,4,or 6 on this device.  The frequency is set by PR2, PR4, or PR6.

Comment: Thank you! I am now using the Timer4 to set the PWM timebase and I have solved the issue.